# Loop CSS3 animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Theres this really cool tutorial on tutorial zine for spinning newspapers i would like to know how to loop the animation, in other words start it again when it finishes its first run.
It runs on jquery and javascript. Heres the JS code

```
$(window).load(function(){

    var imgPath = "assets/img/";

    // Define 6 paper covers:

    var papers = [
        {
            line1:"The financial",
            line2:"chrisis is a hoax!",
            subtitle:"Economist admits practical joke"
        }, {
            line1:"Deeply fried now",
            line2:"considered healthy",
            subtitle:"Scientists change the definition of \"Healthy\""
        }, {
            line1:"Apple announces",
            line2:"the new iphone 9",
            subtitle:"5, 6, 7 and 8 deemed \"not hip enough\""
        }, {
            line1:"The world did end",
            line2:"on may 21st!",
            subtitle:"Priest argues we are actually dead"
        }, {
            line1:"France imposes an",
            line2:"internet kitten tax",
            subtitle:"Posting a cat picture on the internet will cost €3"
        }, {
            line1:"Thank you &",
            line2:"goodbye",
            subtitle:"The Zine Weekly takes its farewell"
        }
    ];

    // Check whether canvas and CSS3 animations are supported:

    if(!$.support.canvas){
        $('#fin').html('Sorry, your browser does not<br />support &lt;canvas&gt;').show();
        return;
    }

    if(!$.support.css3Animation){
        $('#fin').html('Sorry, your browser does not<br />support CSS3 Animations').show();
        return;
    }

    // Use jQuery.Deferred to bind a callback when all
    // the images that comprise the paper are loaded:

    $.when(

        loadImage(imgPath+"paper_top.png"),
        loadImage(imgPath+"paper_left.png"),
        loadImage(imgPath+"paper_center.jpg"),
        loadImage(imgPath+"paper_right.png"),
        loadImage(imgPath+"paper_bottom.png")

    ).then(function( imgTop, imgLeft, imgCenter, imgRight, imgBottom ){

        // Loop through the paper covers and
        // create a new canvas for each one:

        $.each(papers,function(i){

            var canvas  = document.createElement("canvas"),
                c       = canvas.getContext("2d");

            canvas.width = 717;
            canvas.height = 526;

            c.drawImage( imgTop, 0, 0 );
            c.drawImage( imgLeft, 0, 12 );
            c.drawImage( imgCenter, 14, 12 );
            c.drawImage( imgRight, 711, 12 );
            c.drawImage( imgBottom, 0, 516 );

            // Drawing the text using our helper
            // function (see at the bottom):

            drawText( this.line1, this.line2, this.subtitle, c, 358, 250 );

            // Appending the element to the page.
            // This triggers the CSS3 animation.

            setTimeout(function(){
                $("body").append(canvas);
            },i*5800);

        });

        // "This is all"
        $('#fin').delay(papers.length*5800).fadeIn();
    });


    /*------------------------
        Helper functions
    ------------------------*/


    // Load an image by URL and resolve a jQuery.Deferred:

    function loadImage(src){

        var def = new $.Deferred(),
            img = new Image();

        img.onload = function(){

            //  Resolve the deferred. The img parameter
            //  will be available in the then function:

            def.resolve(img);
        }

        // Always set the src attribute
        // after the onload callback:

        img.src = src;

        return def.promise();
    }

    // Draw two lines of text and a subtitle
    // on the canvas (passed as the c param):

    function drawText( line1, line2, subtitle, c, x, y ){

        c.font = "65px Anton,Calibri";
        c.textAlign = "center";
        c.fillStyle = "#3e3e3e";

        c.fillText(line1.toUpperCase(),x,y);
        c.fillText(line2.toUpperCase(),x,y+80);

        c.font = "italic 20px Georgia,serif";
        c.fillStyle = "#737373";

        c.fillText(subtitle,x,y+120);
    }
});

(function(){

    // Adding custom checks for canvas and css3
    // animations support, to the jQuery.support object:

    $.support.canvas = 'getContext' in document.createElement('canvas');

    $.support.css3Animation = (function(){
        var sp = $('<span>');

        return (
            sp.css("-webkit-animation") !== undefined   ||
            sp.css("-moz-animation") !== undefined      ||
            sp.css("animation") !== undefined
        );

    })();
})();
```

Comment: I would think the jQuery `.trigger()` would work here...

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick and naive implementation of looping.  The trouble is that it appends to the body each time.  You would need to modify it a bit to remove the last element when completed.

```
//change this:
setTimeout(function(){
    $("body").append(canvas);
},i*5800);

//to this:
setInterval(function(){
    $("body").append(canvas);
},i*5800);

//remove this:
$('#fin').delay(papers.length*5800).fadeIn();
```